# Error "Notice: Undefined offset: 1" when I activate plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, function, class, plugins

I try to write simple plugin om WordPress. But when I try activate it, I get errow "Notice: Undefined offset: 1" How I fix it? Thank you for your attention.

```
if (!defined('ABSPATH')) {
   die;
}

class ledproperty {

   public function register() {
      add_action('init', [$this, 'custom_post_type']);
   }

   public function custom_post_type() {
      register_post_type('property', 
      array(
         'public' => true,
         'has_archive' => true,
         'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'properties'),
         'label' => 'Property',
         'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail')
      
      ));
   }

   static function activation() {
      flush_rewrite_rules();
   }
   static function deactivation() {
      flush_rewrite_rules();
   }
}
if(class_exists('ledproperty')) {
   $ledproperty = new ledproperty();
   $ledproperty -> register();
}

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, array($ledproperty), 'activation');
register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, array($ledproperty), 'deactivation');
```